# FLEX : How do you get the key names of an array ? keynames of an array?

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, key

I've been seaching on how to get the key names of a flex Array as there is no such function in the Array class. Here is my answer that may be usueful to any of you.

Comment: I wouldn't use Array class as an associative array. Use Object or Dictionary instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        protected function getArrayKeys(a:Array):void
        {
            for (var key:String in a)
            {
                trace (key);
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

I have created sample application to demonstrate associative arrays

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
               >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;


            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var o1:Object = new Object();
                var o2:Object = new Object();

                //these access methods are equivalent:

                //By property
                o1.x = "Object1 xValue";
                o1.y = "Object1 yValue";

                //By indexer
                o2["x"] = "Object2 xValue";
                o2["y"] = "Object2 yValue";

                //Access object properties by name
                trace (o1.x);
                trace (o1.y);

                trace (o2.x);               
                trace (o2.y);               

                //dumpObject uses indexer to access key values
                dumpObject(o1);
                dumpObject(o2);

            }

            protected function dumpObject(o:Object):void
            {
                for (var key:String in o)
                {
                    //loop through property names and access values by indexer.
                    trace ("Key = " + key + ". Value = " + o[key]);
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

Also note, that using Object you are restricted to String for key type. You can have an associative array with key type other then String using Dictionary class.

Comment: You can also do this with Object instead of Array.

Comment: I dont know how its work but its work also and its fastest i guess ! :)

Comment: In AS3 for (... in) loops through object proprties, but for each(... in) loops through array or collection items.

Comment: BTW When you are using Array as an associative array it actually creates properties in underlying Object, as Array is also derived from Object. So as Florian mentioned above there is no reason in using Array instance for an associative array.

Comment: thanks for all info. So if I understand well, you mean that there is no reason to instanciate an Array to have an associative array in fact ? You mean that you can do that with instanciating only Object ? How you do that ?

Comment: @Fabien I've created sample app. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the work. Its my poor knowlegde about Object that make me so bad on finding a solution for associative array. I see now that there was a faster solution to what I did. Thus, in my code, I will keep the Array type as it give some useful function that I may need later (in comparaison to a standard Object type object). Thanks you all for the explanations ! Its more clear in my head now.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

    var __arCurrent:Array=new Array();
    __arCurrent["x"]=10;
    __arCurrent["y"]=20;

    //Get class info of __arCurrent to get the keys name of the array
    var classInfoArray:Object=ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(__arCurrent);

    //For each key of the array __arCurrent
    for(var i:int=0;i<classInfoArray.properties.length;i++){
        var keyname:String = classInfoArray.properties[i].localName;
    }
```

Comment: if its help you, please post a comment. :)